# JQuery Mobile and ASP.NET MVC navbar button active state not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

```
 <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="navBtnThirty" href="@Url.Action("View", "VesselLogs", new { id = @ViewContext.ViewData["VesselGID"], ShowDays = 30})" class="navbarbtn ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">30 Days</a></li>
            <li><a id="navBtnSixty"  href="@Url.Action("View", "VesselLogs", new { id = @ViewContext.ViewData["VesselGID"], ShowDays = 60 })" class="navbarbtn" >60 Days</a></li>
            <li><a id="navBtnNinty" href="@Url.Action("View", "VesselLogs", new { id = @ViewContext.ViewData["VesselGID"], ShowDays = 90 })" class="navbarbtn" >90 Days</a></li>
            <li><a id="navBtnAll" href="@Url.Action("View", "VesselLogs", new { id = @ViewContext.ViewData["VesselGID"], ShowDays = -1 })" class="navbarbtn"  >All Days</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The active button is correctly showing when the page first gets loaded. after clicking one of these links the active button isn't set until the action is completed and I click the button a second time.

Comment: Looks hardcoded to me, use some logic in the action in order to determine which one should be set as active when the view loads.

Answer (score 0):

String syntax looks wrong to me. I bet there are some compiling errors. In your href attribute tag, remove the double quotes in the inside and replace with single quotes.

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="navBtnThirty" href="@Url.Action('View', 'VesselLogs', new { id = @ViewContext.ViewData['VesselGID'], ShowDays = 30})" class="navbarbtn ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">30 Days</a></li>
        <li><a id="navBtnSixty"  href="@Url.Action('View', 'VesselLogs', new { id = @ViewContext.ViewData['VesselGID'], ShowDays = 60 })" class="navbarbtn" >60 Days</a></li>
        <li><a id="navBtnNinty" href="@Url.Action('View', 'VesselLogs', new { id = @ViewContext.ViewData['VesselGID'], ShowDays = 90 })" class="navbarbtn" >90 Days</a></li>
        <li><a id="navBtnAll" href="@Url.Action('View', 'VesselLogs', new { id = @ViewContext.ViewData['VesselGID'], ShowDays = -1 })" class="navbarbtn"  >All Days</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Totally my bad. Didn't occur to me that you have razor syntax in your href. Just noticed the '@' symbols now.

Comment: Nope, the page doesn't work at all when it's written like this.

Answer (score 0):

The code below fixed the issue, be sure to change what jquery mobile event to bind this on for your particular setup.

```
    $(document).bind('pageshow', 
    function () {
        var days = @ViewContext.ViewData["ShowLogs"];
        $('.navbarbtn').removeClass("ui-btn-active");
        if (days == 30) {
            $('#navBtnThirty').addClass("ui-btn-active");
        } else if (days == 60) {
            $('#navBtnSixty').addClass("ui-btn-active");
        } else if (days == 90) {
            $('#navBtnNinty').addClass("ui-btn-active");
        } else if (days == -1) {
            $('#navBtnAll').addClass("ui-btn-active");
        }
    });
</script>
```